# ERC20 - Whats the difference between transfer vs transferFrom?

Tags: erc-20, openzeppelin

I've been checking out the [OpenZeppelin ERC20 documentation](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc20) and I noticed that there are two ways to transfer ERC20 tokens:

1. using `transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) → bool`
2. combining `approve(address spender, uint256 amount) → bool` with `transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) → bool`

What's the difference? Why use one method vs another?

I'm building a dapp that will let users invest some of their tokens into a de-fi yield protocol and I noticed that they implemented Method 2 instead and I wasn't sure of their rationale.

Disclaimer: I'm a noob to a smart contract development so am trying to improve my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to transfer tokens from your address to another, use `transfer()`, if you need to transfer tokens from an address (that is not you) to another use `transferFrom`. For example, if your function needed to take `amount` of tokens from the caller you'd do

```
IERC20(token).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
```